# Pokémon go won't start on mobile data

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I downloaded and installed version 0.29.2 of pokemon go on my Android phone, running lollipop. The app works fine most of the time, however, when I open the app without a WiFi connection (with mobile data on and working), it gets stuck on around 20% on the loading screen and doesn't budge.

The app works when I open it with a Wi-Fi connection and then leave Wi-Fi range or turn off Wi-Fi after it has passed the loading screen. However, the app will not pass the loading screen without WiFi. (Edit: Hotspots don't work either)

I've tried all the usual solutions - restarting, clearing cache, reinstalling, turning off and on mobile data. None of them work.

Any idea how I can start the app when I'm not in WiFi range?

Comment: There could also be server issues in your area (or throughout the game at large), which have been flaring up in the past week. I've noticed that at times the game loads fine on WiFi but not on a 4G connection, other times it won't load at all.

Comment: I also get this bug and it's definitely not server issues nor 3g issues since it works via Wifi and friends are able to connect using iPhones. Oh and it only affects login. It's definitely something specific to some android phones which kills the game if one can't access a wifi spot to login. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: It works with WiFi but not with mobile data. I live outside the US, I tried everything suggested (allow less secure apps in gmail, created another gmail account, created another Pokemon Trainer Club account, hotspot, etc), and nothing worked. It used to work sometimes 2 weeks earlier. I've seen a some people facing same problem so it's not just me. That means there is one thing left, **the cause**: _the company did something on purpose to stop some players outside the US to play the game_. **What you can try**: _use a VPN app, like vpnbook.com (use VPN at your own risk, I don't recommend it)_

Comment: The problem is still there have you find an other solution so far ?

Comment: Pokemon go was geo-blocked where I live, and it still hasn't released yet here. When it does release, I'll see if i still experience the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if '*Restrict app background data*' is turned on.

To do that for an individual app:
Go to **Settings** -> **Apps** -> *[The App]* -> **Data Usage**

There is a little slider that says 'Restrict app background data'. Make sure it is turned off for **Pokemon Go**, **Google Play Store** and **Google Play Services**.

Make sure they are all turned off. In my personal experience, this solved the problem of not being able to log in without WiFi.

Comment: have u try it ? i want to try your answer but it is really unclear because i don't see how i can restrict app backgroud data to off for all google services at once ? More Explanation please :)

Comment: I changed my answer after rechecking the progress. Should be more clear now.

Comment: Hey that was my problem !!! The Google Play Store/Google Play Services were restricted :) yeahhhhhhhh i don't have this anoying bug anymore !!

Comment: Please post your answer on these post too !! http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274479/pokemon-go-will-not-load-or-sign-in, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277019/why-cant-i-connect-to-pokemon-go-via-mobile-data maybe it will help other player  ! :) Have a good day : ps Thank you really mutch !

Comment: Feel free to upvote my answer, and link in those questions to this one :) I think it's in the nature of this site to keep answers as central as possible.

Comment: You're my hero!

Answer (score 1):

Since Pokemon GO is working with WiFi it must work with mobile data too. This can not be the applications fault, the problem must lie in **connectivity of 3G**.

May I ask, perhaps you have limited connection? Meaning you have used all the data you had for that month or other time period and now you're stuck with very slow *down/up* speeds.

If that's not the case then you can try to use the same SIM card in another mobile phone to figure out if your 3G causes the problem.

You can also do a quick [speed test](http://www.speedtest.net) to figure out the speeds for your connection.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I don't think the problem is with my 3G. I haven't reached monthly data limit. Although I didn't speedtest it, i can load full web pages and YouTube videos at fairly decent speeds. Also, note that Pokemon Go DOES work on mobile data provided that I start the app on WiFi and then turn off WiFi on my phone. It's just that the app doesn't start on mobile data.

Comment: Have you tried reassigning your Google account to your phone?

Comment: I can connect and play the game in germany with H+ and 64kBit/s (limited)

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue in early days, same as my gf, sis and a friend. My gf clean-reinstalled, my sis just erased all the PkmnGo data. All my friend did, was just getting another friend and she turned on her android's hotspot, then he connected and voila, went back to his mobile data and PkmnGo worked like a charm.

Comment: @ricardo you can try one of those options and tell us what happened

Comment: I tried all 3 - reinstall, erasing data, and using somebody's hotspot. None of them worked. The app will only start on a WiFi signal that isn't hotspot.

Comment: have you tried login from a different account?

Comment: For me i can connect from a hotspot but this doesn't fix the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

To play Pokemon Go you must have WIFI on. If you want to play using data, keep wifi on and put on data.