# Why can't I connect to Pokemon Go via mobile data?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

It connects to Pokemon Go via wi-fi perfectly fine, but when I try and connect to Pokemon Go via 3G it just gets stuck at the first bar on the loading screen with the eventual pop up saying "Failed to get player information from the server." My 3G connection works perfectly fine with every other app I have, and has been easily able to stream HD videos so I can't see connectivity with 3G being an issue.

It makes even less sense as once connected via wi-fi, the game easily continues to operate via mobile data once I leave the house. However once the app crashes (which it usually does after 15-30 minutes) I try to reload it on mobile data and it gets stuck on the loading screen. If I can find a local free wi-fi spot nearby I can re-connect easily, and then move back onto mobile data.

I've tried removing and reinstalling Pokemon Go and that didn't work. I also reset all my app preferences on my phone and that didn't work.

Not sure if this helps, my phone is a Huawei P8, Android version 5.0.1.  I signed up to Pokemon Go using my Google account.

Comment: This may be due to Google not identifying you properly. I've encountered a similar situation with my Google account with 2 factor authentication, try removing the Google account from your device on mobile data and re-adding it when the game asks you to sign in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tweaking my Google security settings seem to have done the trick, Tomorrow will be the true test!

Comment: Could someone add step-by-step instructions please?

Comment: It works with WiFi but not with mobile data. I live outside the US, I tried everything suggested (allow less secure apps in gmail, created another gmail account, created another Pokemon Trainer Club account, hotspot, etc), and nothing worked. It used to work sometimes 2 weeks earlier. I've seen a some people facing same problem so it's not just me. That means there is one thing left, **the cause**: _the company did something on purpose to stop some players outside the US to play the game_. **What you can try**: _use a VPN app, like vpnbook.com (use VPN at your own risk, I don't recommend it)_

Comment: I guess this would make sense before they released it outside of the US, but now it's officially available in the UK (I downloaded it via the official page on the Android Play Store) then this does not make sense anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a new account using Pokemon Trainer Club.

There seems to be a routing problem for the google login servers affecting only a small unknown set of people.
Although this means you will have to start anew, the game is more fun if you can just walk freely without having do some weird WLAN hopping.

Comment: If I still have trouble tomorrow I'll use the new Pokemon Trainer Club account I've set up. Weird that one of if not the biggest technology companies - Google - has server issues with Pokemon Go....

Comment: I think the "weird WLAN hopping" is the best solution for me as I've advanced several levels. But for those who have very recently started, creating a new Pokemon Trainer Club account as Steve Meyer suggests is (hopefully) the solution.

Comment: I've accepted Steve Meyer's answer as is it the best solution for me. I eventually got fed up with the issues with connecting (even when connected on mobile data the game constantly has the loading sumbol in the top left and freezes). Now I've signed in using Pokemon Trainer Club I can connect easily on mobile data and the connection feels so much smoother. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.  The way I solved it was to go into my google account settings and allow for less secure apps to access my google account.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this seems to have resolved it! I'll test again tomorrow and let you know if it's permanently resolved it.

Comment: So we have to give away more privacy for a reliable connection? It doesn't make any sense! Any idea why these are related?

Comment: Test results were disappointing, sometimes it worked most of the time it didn't...