# Pokémon Go Android Google login loop issue

Tags: pokemon-go

I was logged into my Pokémon Go account this morning when I came across a rare Pokemon and I caught it. I lLogged out of my main account, attempted to log into my other beginner account. When I attempted logging back in... the screen flashed black for a second and went back to the Niantic screen, and then brought me back to the original log in screen. I came across this forum with a similar issue.

[Pokemon Go - Will not load or sign in](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274479/pokemon-go-will-not-load-or-sign-in)

Tried what resolved this users issue however it isn't working for me.

I attempted to fix it by:

- Clearing Cache
- Clearing Data
- Removing google account
- Restarting phone
- Uninstall/reinstall game
- Removing my phone as a device that has accessed my email address

No Google email I use will allow my to bypass this issue. I logged into my account on my girlfriends phone and everything works fine. I logged into a test PTC account and everything works fine.

For the life of me no matter what I do I cant get passed the point where I select my Google account when logging in.

Any advice would be a much appreciated. I've caught over 200 different types and am almost to level 34. I really don't want to go out and get a new phone just to play a game.

Comment: What version of Android do you have? If it's 6.0 or later, you can edit the individual permissions for the app. Maybe try turning those on or off and see what happens? Specifically the contacts one seems to affect the login process, for some reason.

Comment: Just tried removing all permissions. Once I go to login whether I allow or deny each of the 4 permissions is still goes back to the start screen. :/

Comment: Are you willing to do a factory reset on your phone? You'd have to reinstall everything and backup pictures, contacts, etc, but it should clear whatever setting or corrupted file is causing this. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure what would.

Comment: ive thought about it. Ive got a ton of work stuff on my phone. It would take a long time to get everything back up and running